# Check if pipe is empty, UNIX

Tags: c, unix, ipc

I have 2 processes, the parent and the child. Parent process should wait for the user to insert some string and then it should send this string to the child process through a pipe. 
I've successfully done this, but what I'm trying to achieve is to check if the pipe is empty, if it is empty for 60 seconds then the child process should send a signal to its parent.

My Code so far:

```
int main(void)
{
        int     fd[2], nbytes;
        pid_t   childpid;
        char    string[100];
        char    readbuffer[80];
        pipe(fd);

        if((childpid = fork()) == -1)
        {
                perror("fork");
                exit(1);
        }
        else if(childpid > 0) //parent process
        {
                close(fd[0]);
                printf ("Insert a string: ");
                scanf("%s",string);
                /* Send "string" through the output side of pipe */
                write(fd[1], string, (strlen(string)+1));
                exit(0);
        }
        else // child process
        {
                close(fd[1]);
                // check if pipe is empty for 60 seconds 
                nbytes = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
                printf("Received string: %s", readbuffer);
        }
        return(0);
}
```

Comment: Put the pipe in non-blocking mode, and use `select()` with a 60 second timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example where the parent `sleep()`s for a random number of seconds and then `write()`s to the child through the pipe. If the child does not receive the message within 5.5 seconds, it sends `SIGUSR1` to the parent, and the parent does not write the message. This repeats for a specified number of times.

Note that the child waits for 5.5 seconds, rather than 5 seconds, because we're using `sleep()` in the parent which takes whole seconds. This (usually) will leave enough of a time gap to avoid the case where the parent `sleep()`s and the child waits for 5 seconds, and their wires cross in the middle. We could instead use `nanosleep()` in the parent, and have the child wait for a whole number of seconds.

Notes:

1. We can use `select()` with a timeout in the child process, to wait for the specified amount of time. `select()` will return the number of ready file descriptors, so if we only check the pipe and it returns `0`, we know that nothing is ready for reading in the pipe.
2. We can use `sleep()` in the parent to test it out. `sleep()` returns 0 if it slept for the requested time, and non-zero if it was interrupted by a signal, so we can check the return value to figure out which case it was. For your particular case, if you want the parent to get input from the user, `read()` will return `-1` and set `errno` to `EINTR` if it is waiting for user input and receives a signal, so you can detect the timeout in that way. Of course, in this particular use case, it's easier for the parent to just call `select()` itself on `STDIN_FILENO` with your 60 second timeout, rather than have the child wait on the pipe and send a signal.
3. In the child, we have to `FD_ZERO` the `fd_set` and repopulate the `struct timeval` each time through the loop, because `select()` might modify them.
4. We need to register a signal handler for `SIGUSR1` (which does nothing) to avoid the process being terminated when it is received. We don't need the signal handler to do anything, because `sleep()` will tell us via the return value when it was interrupted by a signal, and that's all the information we need, here.

Code:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

#define READ_END 0
#define WRITE_END 1
#define SEC_THRESHOLD 5
#define LOOP_TIMES 5
#define BUFFER_SIZE 512

void handler(int signum)
{
    (void) signum;  //  Ignore unused argument
}

int main(void)
{
    int p[2];
    if ( pipe(p) == -1 ) {
        perror("pipe() failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if ( pid == -1 ) {
        perror("fork() failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if ( pid == 0 ) {
        if ( close(p[WRITE_END]) == -1 ) {
            perror("failed to close pipe end in child");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        for ( int i = 0; i < LOOP_TIMES; ++i ) {
            fd_set fds;
            FD_ZERO(&fds);
            FD_SET(p[READ_END], &fds);

            struct timeval timeout;
            timeout.tv_sec = SEC_THRESHOLD;
            timeout.tv_usec = 500000;

            printf("Loop %d: child waiting for %d.5 seconds.\n",
                   i, SEC_THRESHOLD);
            int status = select(p[READ_END] + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
            if ( status == -1 ) {
                perror("select() failed in child");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            else if ( status == 0 ) {
                printf("Loop %d: timed out in child, sending signal.\n", i);
                kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
            }
            else {
                char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
                if ( read(p[READ_END], buffer, BUFFER_SIZE - 1) == -1 ) {
                    perror("read() failed in child");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                printf("Loop %d: child read: [%s]\n", i, buffer);
            }
        }

        if ( close(p[READ_END]) == -1 ) {
            perror("failed to close read end of pipe in child");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    else {
        if ( close(p[READ_END]) == -1 ) {
            perror("failed to close pipe end in parent");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        struct sigaction sa;
        sa.sa_handler = handler;
        sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
        sa.sa_flags = 0;
        sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);

        srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

        for ( int i = 0; i < LOOP_TIMES; ++i ) {
            const char * msg = "Message to child";
            const int wait_time = rand() % 6 + 3;

            printf("Loop %d: parent waiting for %d seconds...\n", i, wait_time);
            int status = sleep(wait_time);
            if ( status == 0 ) {
                printf("Loop %d: parent sending message to child.\n", i);
                if ( write(p[WRITE_END], msg, strlen(msg)) == -1 ) {
                    perror("write() error in parent");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            }
            else {
                printf("Loop %d: parent interrupted by signal.\n", i);
            }
        }

        if ( close(p[WRITE_END]) == -1 ) {
            perror("failed to close write end of pipe in parent");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    }

    if ( waitpid(pid, NULL, 0) == -1 ) {
        perror("waitpid() failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and sample output session:

```
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox$ ./sigpipe
Loop 0: parent waiting for 7 seconds...
Loop 0: child waiting for 5.5 seconds.
Loop 0: timed out in child, sending signal.
Loop 1: child waiting for 5.5 seconds.
Loop 0: parent interrupted by signal.
Loop 1: parent waiting for 7 seconds...
Loop 1: timed out in child, sending signal.
Loop 2: child waiting for 5.5 seconds.
Loop 1: parent interrupted by signal.
Loop 2: parent waiting for 6 seconds...
Loop 2: timed out in child, sending signal.
Loop 3: child waiting for 5.5 seconds.
Loop 2: parent interrupted by signal.
Loop 3: parent waiting for 5 seconds...
Loop 3: parent sending message to child.
Loop 4: parent waiting for 3 seconds...
Loop 3: child read: [Message to child]
Loop 4: child waiting for 5.5 seconds.
Loop 4: parent sending message to child.
Loop 4: child read: [Message to child]
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox$
```

so we can see that each iteration the parent gets interrupted if the child reaches its 5.5 second timeout, and successfully sends the message in all other cases.